# How do I backup a 5.8 GB directory with a large zip and other file in a WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I started working for `WordPress` Backup & Restore plugin development like `Updraftplus` and `backupbuddy`.
I work with special database tables and data (uploads folders of content folder).
I used a `GitHub` backup code, but it said `"allowed memory limit"` or `"out of memory`."
I am trying in local `WordPress` site, so it will be done by each update of wamp `php.ini`, but usually `WordPress` plugins work on the `WordPress` hosting site, so `WordPress` plugins should work with the default setting, which means everything should be done in the plugins' code.
I've already implemented local restoring function using `PHP` upload chunking,
but it didn't solve the memory limit issue of a too large file directory (now `5.8G`).
If you are interested in my issue, help me. Thanks.

Comment: Code has already posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47326062/when-i-create-zip-file-of-file-directory-with-big-zip-file-in-php-i-am-facing-m/47344028#47344028 about issue

Comment: error image: http://kkliw2017.com/Jincowboy/point.png

Comment: I tried to use this code:

Comment: else if (is_file($file)) {
$zip->addFile($file, basename($file));
}

Comment: my file directory 2.6Gbye zip file and 2.3Gbyte zip file and other
so When i run to backup, its temp file is increasing then it is initializing in 2750mbyte and it is backing other zip file.
then last non zip file creation.